# ArrayList of objects and abstract

Tags: java, arraylist, wildcard, subtyping

I am trying to learn wildcards in Java. Here I am trying to modify the `printCollection` method so that it will only take a class which extends `AbstractList`. It shows the error in comment. I tried to use an `ArrayList` of objects, it works fine. I am using Java 7.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Subtype {
    void printCollection(Collection<? extends AbstractList<?>> c) {
        for (Object e : c) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subtype st= new Subtype();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("a");
        al.add("n");
        al.add("c");
        al.add("f");
        al.add("y");
        al.add("w");
        //The method printCollection(Collection<? extends AbstractList<?>>) in the type Subtype is not applicable for the 
        // arguments (ArrayList<String>)
        st.printCollection(al);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd only want to allow lists that extend `AbstractList` and not all lists that implement the `List` interface (contract)? By specifying `AbstractList` you're coupling your code to a specific implementation. Whenever possible, you should code to interfaces instead of implementations.

Comment: @MickMnemonic  thanks i will keep this in mind .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a Collection of AbstractList Objects, for example a list, filled with AbstractLists. Is that really what you intended?

One way of solving it would be...

```
<T extends AbstractList<?>> void printCollection(T c) {
```

...this way, your method will only accept objects extending AbstractLists with any generic content.

But as other commenters, posters and writers (J. Bloch: Effective Jave, p134+) have already and correctly pointed out, the better style would be simply trying something like this:

```
void printCollection(AbstractList<?> c) {
```

Comment: thanks you are correct but i cannot understand how this works

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot really re-iterate what takes a good book pages to explain here. I suggest refering to some Java Generics tutorial or book.

Comment: i used this link to read about wildcards https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Good idea, but for a beginner, there are probably more basic explanations out there than the oracle documentation which tends to be ok, if you ask me, but not really newbie-friendly.

Comment: just give me few more good links i will surely accept this answer

Comment: I am still sorry, but it's been a long time since I read something about this when I was new, so I really don't know any good links that I could recommend. Technically, I picked up generics on the way (which lead to many confusions). Perhaps this might help you, but as I said, can't guarantee for anything: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.de/2011/03/java-generics-tutorial-part-i-basics.html

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: the only thing I would add to your answer is that the formal type parameter, `T`, appears only once in the method signature.  In this case, a more flexible API is presented by using bounded wildcards instead (Effective Java, 2nd Ed. J. Block).

Comment: @scottb It has to be kept in mind that this is not a universal rule: T in the position of the return type is often the only appearance of the type parameter. T may also need to be referred to in method body.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you assume the parameter should implement `Collection` and should **contain** elements that extends `AbstractList`

```
void printCollection(Collection<? extends AbstractList<?>> c)
```

To get what you want you could simply write it like this:

```
void printCollection(AbstractList<?> c)
```

Comment: I think that this is a better answer.  Using bounded wildcards in the method signature, where possible, can yield a more flexible API.